# Secure? Javascript library stored on server, users are logged in

Tags: javascript, security

I am considering referencing a known JavaScript library from within some corporate reporting software and have a question regarding security.

The library would be stored on the reporting server rather than referencing it directly from the library author's web site.

There are a limited number of end-users of the report, and those users are securely logged in through the reporting software and vpn.

Am I at risk of endangering our data by using javascript this way?

There will be no user-inputted data, it will just used to map/visualize our data based on user queries.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any way that JavaScript could negatively effect your stored data. It might interact with it, but there's surely no write/delete capability from within a JS library.

Comment: Set Sail - Thank you for your response, that's what I thought.  Could it somehow allow someone (who is not securely logged in) to access the data?

Comment: No, why would it? The JS does not manage the access authorisation of your data (does it???). However, if written badly, it might open up attack vectors (e.g. XSS) in your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Any JS code that you run in your origin will allow it to read HTTP responses from that origin (or accessible CORS resources) with the user's cookies.

Therefore, you're allowing the people who control that JS to impersonate your users.

Comment: SLaks, but what if the JS library is downloaded and stored on my secured server, rather than linking directly to the third-party library?

Comment: @user1252489: Have you carefully read the code to make sure that it isn't already doing bad things?  (or loading other 3rd-party scripts)

Comment: No third-party scripts are being loaded.

Comment: @user1252489: You still need to trust the code you're hosting yourself, which is harder if you didn't write it.